# How to configure gstreamer resolution

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer

I have working command to stream video over network.

```
gst-launch -v v4l2src device=/dev/video7 ! autoconvert ! theoraenc ! rtptheorapay ! udpsink host=[DESTINATION HOST]
```

How can I change resolution of this videoflow before sending video to the network?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a capsfilter to force a specific format, like:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video7 ! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw, width=<width>, height=<height>" ! autoconvert ! theoraenc ...
```

If you are using gstreamer 0.10 (which you shouldn't, it is 2 years obsolete now), you need to use "video/x-raw-yuv, width=, height=; video/x-raw-rgb, width=, height=" instead.

If you select a format that your video input doesn't support it will fail with a negotiation issue. If you don't care and just want a specific resolution even if it is not directly supported by the camera you can put the capsfilter after the autoconvert.